# How To Use map() on a Function with Many Variables, and On Combinations Using Itertools

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm currently studying pythons, subproccess() with map() in order to integrate it to my program.

Let's say I have a loop like this,

```
for a, b in itertools.combinations(exchanges, 2):  
    if (a != None and b != None):
        symbols =  a.symbols
        symbols1 = b.symbols

        if symbols is not None and symbols1 is not None:
            symbols = [x for x in symbols if x is not None]
            symbols1 = [x for x in symbols1 if x is not None]

            if symbol != None and symbol in symbols and symbol in symbols1:                      
                 execute_function(a, b, symbol, expent,amount)
```

obviously I want my symbols and symbol1 lists mapped to the function and get it one by one.

and try different combination with it using itertools.

Tried this so far(just for mapping, as I have no knowledge on how to do that itertools comparing in this case), but seems to be returning a nonetype error. Object not callable.

```
pool = Pool()
pool.map(execute_func(a, b, symbol, expent,amount), symbols)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In what you tried, the error is that the first argument of `pool.map()` should be a function but you are passing the *result* of the function, since you are calling it with `a, b, symbol, expent, amount`.

From what I understand, you want to call the function `execute_func` for all non-None symbols pair of all two-by-two combinations of the elements of `exchanges`. Then, I suggest you write the loops and non-None testing as a generator and then pass it to `pool.map`. Here's a sketch of my solution:

```
def gen_all_symbol_pairs(sequence):
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(sequence, 2):  
        if a is not None and b is not None:
            if a.symbols is not None and b.symbols is not None:
                for symbol in a.symbols:
                    if symbol is not None and symbol in b.symbols:
                        yield a, b, symbol

with Pool() as pool:
     pool.starmap(lambda a, b, symb: execute_func(a, b, symb, expent, amount), gen_all_symbol_pairs(exchanges))
```

Here, `gen_all_symbol_pairs` is an iterable that generates all non-None symbol pairs. Also, I used a `lambda` function to * partially* fill the `execute_func` function. Finally, I used `pool.starmap` so that every sequence yielded by the generator is *star expanded* in three arguments.

Hope this helps!